# Convert C++ structure to C# to read memory Mapped File/Shared Memory Object

Tags: c#, c++, .net

While SharedMemoryObject (SMO)/ Memory Mapped Files are created and opened in same language looks good. 
But, in my situation, SMO gets created in C++ for below structure.

```
typedef struct  {
    BOOL    IsLoaded;
    BYTE    pBuffer[120];
} MyStruct;

typedef struct  {
    DWORD   threadId;
    DWORD   values[5];
    char    exePath[250];
    BOOL    isThreadAlive; 
    MyStruct myData;
    DWORD   CurrentThreadInfo;
} SharedDataArea;
```

I need to read this detail using C#. So currently I am able to read Integers and Bytes, but Char pointers and arrays are giving me trouble.

Is there any way to convert/map the above C++ structure into C# code, so I can read SMO in standard way? I don't want to hardcode the offsets of the parameter.

Comment: Post a [mcve] you have written to try to do this and then say what is wrong with it.   Stack overflow isn't a site to have people write your code for you.

Comment: Have you read Microsoft's documentation about Marshaling structs and arrays between C# and unmanaged systems?...

Comment: ... See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-structures-using-pinvoke), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/z6cfh6e6%28v%3dvs.100%29), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr_)